# Pre- and post-build steps in Python Tools For Visual Studio

Tags: python, msbuild, visual-studio-2013, ptvs

I'm trying to switch over from Aptana to PTVS but I'm stymied by an inability to configure the build process.   I'd like to add a pre-build step that runs some tests and a post-build step that runs a zip packager / deployment script -- however I'm totally unable to figure out how to add these to PTVS.

In  a C# project (for example) I could right click on the project file to get a configuration page which allows editing pre and post build targets.  In PVTS that configuration page doesn't exist. My efforts to tweak the .pyproj file by hand have also be unsuccessful. I added a target tag (the way you would in, eg, c#) and was told that the element 'target' did not recognize the attribute 'name' - even though that's how it's specified in all the MS build configs I've ever seen elsewhere.

Is this possible? If so, how can I set it up?

Comment: why would you use VS? ... meh totally not helpful, but that just seems like pain for pains sake

Comment: PTVS is a pretty decent editor with good code completion and performance. It also gets me out of having two completely different sets of UI and hotkeys for C# and Python

Comment: In my case, almost all of the projects in the solution are C++, but this one project is Python and I would rather deal with it in the IDE instead of going to the command line to do everything.  But it depends on protobuf files in the other projects, but needs to compile them for Python instead of C++ -- thus the desire to setup custom steps in a python project. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible as of PTVS 2.0. It simply doesn't run any target on "build" (the fact that it shows "Building" in the Output window is really more of an artifact of VS, which has a mandatory build step for projects). That said, we have an outstanding [feature request](https://pytools.codeplex.com/workitem/945) for this, and recognize the value of scripting various packaging and similar task through MSBuild.

We are not doing this exact thing for the upcoming 2.1 release, but there is something similar that might help you - since "building" does not actually make sense by itself for Python, we are instead allowing you to define commands in MSBuild that are exposed in Visual Studio UI on the project node in Solution Explorer; those commands can be backed by an arbitrary Python script. Have a look at these to see what this looks like (bearing in mind, of course, that this is an actively developed feature, and the code will probably change as we are working on it):

https://pytools.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Python/Product/BuildTasks/Microsoft.PythonTools.targets
https://pytools.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Python/Product/Django/Microsoft.PythonTools.Django.targets

(search for `<PythonCommand>`)

We don't have a dev build that includes those changes yet to easily play with it, but we should get one out soon. You can, of course, just take the most recent sources and build them.

Comment: PTVS actually will get this in 2.1 as NTVS already has it and that'll get merged over.  Whether we have any UI for pre/post build steps is another question.  If we don't though you can still add: a <Target Name="MyStep" AfterTargets="Build"> </Target> in your .pyproj and include an Exec task in there or whatever you want.  You can also do BeforeTargets for the pre-build step.